# Scheme function that returns the shortest of the two lists

Tags: function, scheme

you must return a function that returns the shorter of the two lists. Wrote such function, but there is an error:

> else: not allowed as an expression in: (else (sh (cdr shA) (cdr shB)))

I don't know how to fix it.

```
(define (shorter a b)
  (let sh ((shA a) (shB b))
    (cond
      (((null? shA) a)
       ((null? shB) b)
       (else (sh (cdr shA) (cdr shB)))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got too many parentheses - this is an entire expression:

```
(((null? shA) a)
 ((null? shB) b)
 (else (sh (cdr shA) (cdr shB))))
```

and you can't have `else` in that position.

The syntax is `(cond clause1 clause2 ...)`, not `(cond (clause1 clause2 ...))`, so you need

```
(define (shorter a b)
  (let sh ((shA a) (shB b))
    (cond
       ((null? shA) a)
       ((null? shB) b)
       (else (sh (cdr shA) (cdr shB))))))
```